# how to Perform Backspace operation in TextBox using KeyCode '8' in C# asp.net.?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am developing Macro application in C# asp.net , for that i need to keep track of all the key that i had pressed from keyboard. here i found that the KeyCode for "Backspce"  is 8.
but when i used String.fromCharCode(8), it gives specialCharcter('square box') insted performing Backspace operation. 
This problem is also same for other Special Character like Up,Down,Left,Right arrow keys,Delete key,etc.
(note : here i had use JavaScript for getting Character's KeyCode.. )

Thank You in Advance....

Comment: Here, want to perform Backspace operation in text using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to adjust it's value:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="whatever" id="theInput" />
<button id="delete">Backspace</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
document.getElementById('delete').addEventListener('click', function()
{
    var theInput = document.getElementById('theInput');
    theInput.value = theInput.value.substr(0, theInput.value.length - 1);
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jwQbh/1/

Comment: I do not want to prevent Backspace. Here , i want to perform BackSpace Operation.

Comment: @Mihir: Sorry. You weren't clear enough. I changed my answer.

Comment: :This is not an actual problem.let me explain in brief . Let i have a text "Mihir" and then i pressed 'Backspace' for 3 times. at this time my recorded keycodes are "77,73,72,73,82,8,8,8" .now when i convert this keycode in to string at that time i got "mihir[][][]". here i wnt only "mi". this problem is same for other Special Charcter like Delete key, up,down,right,left Arrow key. Thank You.

Comment: Can you post the code for how you 'record keycodes'?  Assuming you are doing some kind of concatenation in that function, you could check for char 8 and remove the last item rather than adding it.

Comment: You are right if i have problem with only "BackSpace". Look Forward: http://mihirlakdawala.webs.com/apps/blog/show/8099983-stackoverflow